# How to create a hierarchy header higher than chapter but lower than part on KOMA Script

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

I am working on a legal document with KOMA Script and I need to create a higher order header to chapter that instead of "Chapter" says "Title" but without numbering, because that numbering will go in ordinal and with word and not number, i. e."First Title","Second Title", etc... In addition, some of these "titles" will have a name, which should be an optional argument, for example "Fourth title: of the standing committee".

I know titlesec exists and it's an excellent package for cases like this, but since I'm using `KOMA Script`, I'm pretty sure there is an alternative way to do it within `KOMA Script`, but I don't know which one. Any clues?

An MWE attempt, for now, may be the following:

```
 \documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=letter,headings=small,DIV=calc,headsepline=true,titlepage=on,BCOR=5mm,parskip=half*]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\part[First Title]{First title: the title of this first title}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

---

### Update

In response to the request to show the structure of the document (Constitution) I am working on, I add an image of one of the most representative pages.

[image: Representative page of the Constitution]

The part with which I have a problem is the one I've already mentioned. I do not know if it is a problem unique to my country, legal documents in my language, or a common feature of legal documents in the world, but I have the impression that it is documents with a rather irregular structure that solves certain needs of different (and divergent) forms in the same document.

In this case, I have constitutional articles divided into paragraphs, others into fractions (more often than not) with different enumeration sequences, and other times in addition to fractions, there are another kind of sections over the fractions.

---

My interest is not to correct or standardize all these inconsistencies, but to put them in writing and to show the changes (which are very many) in a chronological way that have occurred in the drafting of the Constitution during the century that is in force.

Comment: A MWE is always great and helpful. As for what you want: Do you need something like a `\part` that instead of part is labeled with title? How about toc entries, running headers etc.?

Comment: Take a look in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) and there search for the command `\DeclareSectionCommand`.

Comment: If you don't need `\part` redefine `\part` to do what you want. Otherwise move `\part` one level higher in the hierarchy and define your new title macro at the original `\part` level.

Comment: BTW, chapter is 0, part is -1 (default).

Comment: Give us an example of your hierarchy, your structure. The German BGB e.g. is structured in books, sections, titles, subtitles, chapters. But these are only names and it would be easy to rename the KOMAscript level »chapter« to »Buch«, so a new chapter would appear as »Buch 1«. The BGB-section remains a section, but the subsection would become »title«. And so on.

Comment: @KeksDose Interesting fact, what I am dealing with is similar to the BGB, but it is a Constitution structured in titles, chapters, sections, articles and fractions. I still don't know how to implement the articles, but the fractions of the articles can be arranged with numbered lists.

Comment: @Aradnix in this case, redefine the `\part`s to be your titles (`\RedeclareSectionCommand` to change formatting), use `\chapter` and `\section` as they are, redefine `\subsection` to be your articles and `\subsubsection` to be your fractions. This setup should do.

Comment: Please provide more details, edit your question. Maybe upload a copy of a page of the constitution. Is it supposed to be »1 First Title« or »First Title: ...«, do you need sectionnames, e.g. »section 1: sectiontitle«.

Comment: For the fractions of articles use scrjura's contract environment.

Comment: @KeksDose I know about the `scrjura`option but for this document, the scrjura's contract environment doesn't works. Let me search a picture about the constitution for explain better the Title's structure. I'll tell you in advance that the names of the titles are written in ordinal, but without number. Incidentally, the document is not in English, but I think the language in this case is irrelevant. For the same reason, your first choice is wrong, since the titles are ordered with ordinal numbering written in words, not Arabic or Roman numerals.

Comment: @Aradnix Using ordinal numbers is not a general problem. In my answer, two days ago, I've shown ordinal numbering already.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @samcarter Thanks, Thank you, I was out these days and could not fully review the answer (until now I only have one), quite well explained by what I read. I know how to accept the answer, but I didn't do it precisely because I was absent. I don't see the rush either, I myself have written a couple of answers that have gone unaccepted for years. ;)

Comment: @Aradnix Post a picture of the constitution, hablo un pocco espagnol.

Comment: @KeksDose I updated the question with the picture you asked, sorry for the delay.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Thanks and yes, you did it, I'm reading your answer, it's fantastic can use the ordinals in an automatic way in LaTeX also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just redefine `\part` to produce a heading in chapter style without prefix line and change the output of counter `part`, e.g.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=letter,headings=small,DIV=calc,headsepline=true,titlepage=on,BCOR=5mm,parskip=half*]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand*{\OrdWord}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1 0\or First\or Second\or Third\or Forth\else to large\fi
}
\renewcommand*{\thepart}{\OrdWord{\value{part}}}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\thepart~Title}
\renewcommand*{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}{%
    \addtocentrydefault{part}{}{#2}%
  }{%
    \addtocentrydefault{part}{#1~Titel}{}%
  }%
}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=chapter]{part}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{: the title of this first title}

\lipsum
\part{~}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

You have to use `\part{~}` instead of `\part{}` for a part without additional title, because `\part{}` won't produce any entry in the table of contents. Please extend `\OrdWord` as you need it.

If the `chapter` counter should be related to the increase of the `part` counter you can add

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[counterwithin=part]{chapter}
```

As an alternative you can define a new command:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=letter,headings=small,DIV=calc,headsepline=true,titlepage=on,BCOR=5mm,parskip=half*]{scrbook}[2017/12/04]
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand*{\OrdWord}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1 0\or First\or Second\or Third\or Forth\else to large\fi
}
\DeclareSectionCommand[style=chapter,level=-1,tocstyle=chapter,tocindent=0pt,tocnumwidth=6em]{Title}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[counterwithin=Title]{chapter}
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[level=-2,toclevel=-2]{part}
\renewcommand*{\theTitle}{\OrdWord{\value{Title}}}
\renewcommand*{\Titleformat}{\theTitle~Title}
\renewcommand*{\addTitletocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}{%
    \addtocentrydefault{Title}{}{#2}%
  }{%
    \addtocentrydefault{Title}{#1~Titel}{}%
  }%
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Title{: the title of this first title}

\lipsum
\chapter{First Test Chapter in First Title}
\lipsum
\Title{~}
\lipsum
\chapter{First Test Chapter in Second Title}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Output of the second example (first is similar):

[image: Table of Contents] [image: First Title] [image: Second Title]

Please note, that you need an [up-to-date KOMA-Script](https://komascript.de/current) for the second example. You can do the same with KOMA-Script 3.22 or 3.23 but need to set additional options at the declaration of the `\Title` command, e.g.:

```
\DeclareSectionCommand[style=chapter,level=-1,pagestyle=plain,beforeskip=2em,innerskip=0pt,afterskip=1em,font=\huge,prefixfont=\huge,tocstyle=chapter,tocindent=0pt,tocnumwidth=6em]{Title}
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. I've got KOMA-Script 3.24 installed. I need to improve the appearance of the title so that when it has a name, it appears in the bottom line, otherwise it looks bad. I also have to see how to add that name to the table of contents.